# Previous data not clearing in scatter chart in EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, scatter-plot, scatter

I am using scatter and bar chart for same data with pagination logic. While we loading the second page, previous scatter chart data are not clearing.

For example we have 6 records and showing 4 record per page, first 4 records are displayed properly as shown below

[image]

In the second page the 2 records are displayed but previous scatter chart data are not clearing properly as shown below.The issue is i am getting 2 column chart data and four scatter chart data. How can i clear the previous scatter chart data before rendering new page.

[image]

Or else please advice, is there any way to add circle indicator to a bar chart like the images show above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has been fixed recently; the fix should appear in the nightly builds soon. I would also recommend asking questions like that in Sencha forums, there is a greater chance of them being answered there.